# Parsing ical format - Parse exception

Tags: java, android, parsing, icalendar, ical4j

I am using ical4j to parse the ical format on the Android.

My input ics is:

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    SEQUENCE:5
    DTSTART;TZID=US/Pacific:20021028T140000
    DTSTAMP:20021028T011706Z
    SUMMARY:Coffee with Jason
    UID:EC9439B1-FF65-11D6-9973-003065F99D04
    DTEND;TZID=US/Pacific:20021028T150000
    END:VEVENT
    END:VCALENDAR
```

But when I try to parse this I get the exception:

`Error at line 1: Expected [VCALENDAR], read [VCALENDARBEGIN]`

The relevant code is:

```
    HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper(
            "http://10.0.2.2/getcalendar.php", params);
    StringBuilder response = httpHelper.postData();

    StringReader sin = new StringReader(response.toString());
    CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
    Calendar cal = null;
    try {
        cal = builder.build(sin);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("calendar", "io exception" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (ParserException e) {
        Log.d("calendar", "parser exception" + e.getLocalizedMessage());
```

### }

```
public class HttpHelper {
final HttpClient client;
final HttpPost post;
final List<NameValuePair> data;

public HttpHelper(String address, List<NameValuePair> data) {
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    post = new HttpPost(address);
    this.data = data;
}

private class GetResponseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, StringBuilder> {
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            return inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public StringBuilder postData() {
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        return (new GetResponseTask().execute()).get();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
    }
    return null;
}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        total.append(line);
        Log.v("debug", "Line: " + line);
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}
}
```

Comment: According to http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/, the ical code is validated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess would be the line endings in the response string are different from what ical4j expects.

The standard specifies you should use CRLF (aka '\r\n').

Comment: Do you know what the line endings should be? It doesn't seem to be on the ical4j website.

Comment: I'm fetching the response string from a webpage (when I view the source of that webpage I just see that ics input on separate lines), how would I add the CRLF in? Thanks for your help so far

Comment: Let me phrase that better: How can I use php to output it in ics format, so that the php output can be parsed ok?

Comment: Do you have an URL that we could look at to verify the line endings are indeed wrong?

Comment: That file has CRLF line endings like it should. I pulled it through the code you quoted above and it was parsed just fine - even when I replaced the line endings with single CR or LF characters. Can you express the problem as a complete failing test? might be something in the ical4j.properties settings. Which version of ical4j are you using?

Comment: The library version is ical4j-v1.0.

I don't currently have an ical4j.properties file, should there be one?

What do you mean by a complete failing test?

Comment: You have pasted a piece of 'relevant code'. This code seems to work fine here. Can you paste more of it (for example, include a filled 'response' string) so I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: I've posted the rest of the code. Might the problem be that in the inputStreamToString method readLine() returns the line without the line break characters?

Comment: After testing, I can confirm the problem is with the readLine(). I need to manually add \r\n after each line

Answer (score 3):

The input file is valid, the problem is with your method inputStreamToString(), which performs a readLine() on the input (which strips the newlines) and appends to a string without re-adding the newlines.

I would suggest either to use an alternative to readLine() (if you want to preserve newlines from the original file), or append your own newlines in the loop, eg:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
    total.append("\r\n");
    Log.v("debug", "Line: " + line);
}
```